# How to build and run a Qt application from the Windows command line?

Tags: qt, command-line

I'm trying to create a simple Qt project. I  have done inside of a *folder* the following:

- Created a `.ui` file
- ran `qmake -project`
- Made a `.pro` file
- Made a `main.cpp` file

How can I run this project using a command line?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should run `qmake` to generate a `Makefile` from your `.pro`, then run `make` to compile and build the executable binary program, then run that program by its name. You might need to type the full or relative file path of the program if your `PATH` is not containing the directory having the program binary.

Comment: For the program to run by its name is it the `.cpp` file or the `.pro` file?

Comment: it is the executable binary program. I'll guess it has `.exe` suffix on Windows, and usually no suffix on Linux.